# Complex MySQL statement causing error

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to combine two working sql statements into one working sql statement.

Here are the two sql statements that each work when done seperately:

This first one selects all products and the shops that the product is in, and the categories that the product has, for the shops that are in a specific area. It is for displaying the products on a website, then listing the shops and categories of the product under each product.

```
SELECT p.p_id, p.`p_name`, p.brand, 
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT(c.c_id, ':', c.c_name) SEPARATOR ', ' ) as categories, 
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT(s.s_id, ':', s.s_name) SEPARATOR ', ' ) as shops 
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN product_category pc on p.p_id = pc.p_id 
INNER JOIN category c ON c.c_id = pc.c_id 
INNER JOIN product_shop ps on p.p_id = ps.p_id 
INNER JOIN shop s ON s.s_id = ps.s_id 
WHERE s.street = 'college hill' 
AND s.city = 'auckland' 
AND s.province = 'auckland' 
AND s.country = 'new zealand' 
AND s.postalCode = '1011'
```

The results of my top sql statement look like this:

[image]

**Important: I have since added latitude and longitude fields to the shop table which is important for the next sql statements in this question**

This second sql statement is taken from [this link that finds the closest 20 shops to a latlong coordinate in a table of shops](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#finding-locations-with-mysql). I have adapted it to work with my database:

```
SELECT s_id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-36.8473223
) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(174.744227
) ) + sin( radians(-36.8473223
) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM shop HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

It gives this result:

[image]

So by marrying these two sql statements, I can select the products that are in shops closest to a latlong coordinate, to display the products on the website, and then their shops and categories for each product.

All I am trying to do is add the distance of the shop from the given latitude and longitude coordinates (entered by the user with a google autocomplete place object), into the shop select results that I posted an image of for the top sql statement in this question. So in the shops results, for each shop just add a distance result which would be something like 5.897. And return the entries with the closest distance.

Here is my current attempt:

```
    SELECT p.p_id, 
    p.`p_name`, 
    p.brand, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(c.c_id, ':', c.c_name) SEPARATOR ', '
    ) as categories, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(s.s_id, ':', s.s_name, ':', 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-36.8473223
    ) ) * cos( radians( s.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( s.longitude ) - radians(174.744227
    ) ) + sin( radians(-36.8473223
    ) ) * sin( radians( s.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance) SEPARATOR ', '
    ) as shops
    FROM 
    product p 
    INNER JOIN product_category pc on p.p_id = pc.p_id 
    INNER JOIN category c ON c.c_id = pc.c_id 
    INNER JOIN product_shop ps on p.p_id = ps.p_id 
    INNER JOIN shop s ON s.s_id = ps.s_id HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

I am getting this error:

> ## 1583 - Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'

What can I do to fix the error?

result from answer below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an "As Distance" within your concat, then finishing the gorup concat as "Shops".

I have rewritten your query.  The PREQUERY from shops computes your distance and has your limit of 20 entries... THEN it joins to the rest of the chain.  Since "distance" is the computed column, that can now be used in your concat statement.

```
SELECT 
      p.p_id, 
      p.p_name,
      p.brand,
      GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT(c.c_id, ':', c.c_name) 
         SEPARATOR ', ' ) as categories, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(s.s_id, ':', s.s_name, ':', 
         s.distance ) SEPARATOR ', ' ) as shops
   from
      ( SELECT 
              s_id, 
              s.s_name,
              ( 3959 
                * acos( cos( radians( -36.8473223 ) ) 
                * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
                * cos( radians( longitude ) 
                - radians( 174.744227 ) ) 
                + sin( radians( -36.8473223 ) ) 
                * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
           FROM 
              shop 
           HAVING 
              distance < 25 
           ORDER BY 
              distance 
           LIMIT 
              0, 20 ) s
      INNER JOIN product_shop ps 
         ON s.s_id = ps.s_id 
         INNER JOIN product p 
            on ps.p_id = p.p_id
            INNER JOIN product_category pc 
               on p.p_id = pc.p_id 
               INNER JOIN category c 
                   ON pc.c_id = c.c_id
   group by
      p.p_id,
      p.p_name,
      p.brand
```

Comment: Wow, awesome, thanks. For some reason I'm only getting one row back in the results. The expected result is that I get every product in the database back, looking like that row that did come back. Which is about 16 products so 16 rows like the one that did come back. There are only 2 shops in the database, both of which came back in the result for the product that came back. All of the products are in either one, or both, of the two shops. I just need to figure out why the other products are not being returned in the results. Let me know if you have any idea why it only returns one row thanks!

Comment: The result that I do get back is posted at the bottom of my question

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins, added GROUP BY.  Since your original query did not have a group by, it WOULD always return just one row via the group_concat.  Try it now.

Comment: Oh sorry, my original query must have been a bit wrong. Done. Perfect. Thank you!